# IOS current keyframe y axis

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey im trying to show the y axis of my imageview while its moving , but its not displaying the animating y axis , its showing only one number .

```
//LINE ANAMATION
CALayer *layer = line.layer;
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){line.center.x,20};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){line.center.x, screenSizeY/2};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 3.f;
animation.path = thePath;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[layer  addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
NSLog(@"%f", line.center.y);
```

Comment: im trying to get the y axis while the animation is moving , so the  nslog should keep on displaying different y values .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with this. First, the animation state is maintained in the presentation layer. Your view and underlying layer are will reflect the final state of the animation immediately. Second, your `NSLog` statement will only be called once because you aren't in a loop.

If you want to do something at each frame of an animation, you [can use `CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) to get a callback on each frame. In this callback, you can check the current Y position by looking at the presentation layer:

```
- (void)myCallback:(CADisplayLink *)link
{
    NSLog(@"%f", CGRectGetMidY(line.layer.presentationLayer.frame));
}
```

Comment: Im new to objective-c , do you think its possible for you to edit the code i provided and explained what you changed , so i can understand . thank you for the help.